# Fermat's theorem, sum of prime squares.

Tags: number-theory

By Fermat's theorem, a prime $p$, is a sum of two squares if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

I am wondering if there is any extension of this theorem or result that will give me the primes of the form $q^2 + d^2 = p$, where $q$, $d$, $p$ are all primes.

Calculating by hand the first 10 primes of this form (I may have missed some) I notice that they are all of the form ${q_i}^2 + 2^2 = p_i$, where $q_i \in {3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 37, 47, 67, 73, 97}$., Fermat's theorem then $\Rightarrow q_i^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, but this doesn't help much and i have no idea if this pattern continues.

Also, are there infinitely many primes of this form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not known whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2 + 4.$ As a result, it is not known whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $p^2 + 4$ with $p$ prime.

Comment: Can't seem to find much about these primes searching google and this site. Could you provide some links?

Comment: @roslavets https://oeis.org/A045637

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $p$ and $q$ are odd primes, you have that
$$d^2 = p_i - q_i^2 \equiv 1 - 1 = 0 \mod 2$$
so $d$ is an even number. That is, if it is a prime, then $d = 2$.